# Why would an making my ODataController have a plural name stop it from working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm creating a simple project to test out features in Entity Framework. On the front end I want to have a SPA application which interacts with the server using OData API. I set up my first ODataController as below

```
public class BlogPostsController : ODataController
{
    private readonly IBlogPostService _blogPostService;

    public BlogPostsController(
        IBlogPostService blogPostService)
    {
        _blogPostService = blogPostService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<BlogPost> GetBlogPosts()
    {
        return _blogPostService.Queryable();
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<BlogPost> GetBlogPost([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(_blogPostService.Queryable().Where(bp => bp.Id == key));
    }
}
```

My ODataConfig is set up as below

```
public static class ODataConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Entities.BlogPost>(typeof(Entities.BlogPost).Name);
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
        config.AddODataQueryFilter();
    }
}
```

My site is hosted in IIS on my machine and when I access http://localhost/mytestsite/odata/BlogPosts I get a 404. However, if I change my code to change my controller to replace BlogPosts with BlogPost, then I can access the url http://localhost/mytestsite/odata/BlogPost and everything works as expected. My working controller is below

```
public class BlogPostController : ODataController
{
    private readonly IBlogPostService _blogPostService;

    public BlogPostController(
        IBlogPostService blogPostService)
    {
        _blogPostService = blogPostService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<BlogPost> GetBlogPost()
    {
        return _blogPostService.Queryable();
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<BlogPost> GetBlogPost([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(_blogPostService.Queryable().Where(bp => bp.Id == key));
    }
}
```

One other issue is if I try to access http://localhost/FourTen.Blog.Web/odata/blogpost I also get a 404. The only difference is that blogpost in the URL is lower case.

My question is, are there some naming conventions I have missed and why is the URL case sensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because of your configuration.
You register your `EntitySet` with the name **BlogPost** if you replace it with **BlogPosts** it should work.

```
builder.EntitySet<Entities.BlogPost>(typeof(Entities.BlogPost).Name);

builder.EntitySet<Entities.BlogPost>("BlogPosts");
```

Answer (score 1):

I Did a bit more digging and based upon this article, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions, I wasn't following the correct naming convention. My Entity is a BlogPost so I needed a BlogPostController.